# Unexpected tokens (use ; to seperate expressions on the same line) in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I was using kotlin in my android project which is developing on java , I ve used kotlin data classes in my service layer

Now i wants to add alternate tag in serialied

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate={"person", "user"}) val title:String,
```

This gives me unexpected token issue and it seems its from kotlin side

This seems like kotlin issue can someone point me out issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume this will do the job:

```
@SerializedName(value="name", alternate=arrayOf("person", "user")) val title:String
```

**Kotlin** compiler treats `alternate={"person", "user"}` as a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-types).

---

***EDIT by [1blustone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7366707/1blustone):***

In **Kotlin** 1.2 this is possible with [array literals](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations), but only in annotations:

```
@SerializedName(value = "name", alternate = ["person", "user"]) val title:String
```

Comment: Yes it did . so in kotlin i need to use arrayOf  to make a array right ?

Comment: Aye, there's no java-like array initialization in Kotlin.

Comment: Update: now in Kotlin 1.2 you can use the [array literals](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew12.html#array-literals-in-annotations) `[]` (but only in annotations!)